# MeteorJS check if template instance has a DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, meteor

I'm trying to do some DOM manipulation on every evaluation of a helper function, `{{htmlMarkup}}`. The problem is that when the page loads the helper is triggered before the template has a DOM.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    htmlMarkup:function(){
        var tmpl = Template.instance();
        tmpl.$('.code-container').empty();

        Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
            Prism.highlightElement(tmpl.$('.code-container')[0]);
        });
        return input.get();
    }
});
```

I will get the error message `Exception in template helper: Error: Can't use $ on template instance with no DOM`. I have tried to check if `tmpl.firstNode` is undefined but it doesn't work. What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We may check if the template is rendered (and thus have a DOM) with the property `tmpl.view.isRendered` like this:

```
var tmpl = Template.instance();
if(tmpl.view.isRendered){
     //Do DOM manipulation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a property on the template instance when it's getting rendered, and check if it's true in your helper.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.isRendered = false;
});

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function(){
  this.isRendered = true;
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  htmlMarkup:function(){
    var tmpl = Template.instance();
    if(!tmpl.isRendered){
      return input.get();
    }
    tmpl.$('.code-container').empty();
    //
    Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
      Prism.highlightElement(tmpl.$('.code-container')[0]);
    });
    //
    return input.get();
  }
});
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could also use a `Tracker.autorun` inside your `Template.onRendered` handler to execute arbitrary code AFTER every input is detected.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.input = new ReactiveVar("");
});

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function(){
  this.autorun(function(){
    var input = this.input.get();
    //
    this.$(".code-container").empty();
    //
    Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
      Prism.highlightElement(this.$(".code-container")[0]);
    });
  });
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  "input textarea": function(event, template){
     template.input.set(template.$("textarea").val());
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found the best way is to check `Template.instance(). view.isRendered`